# Offline survey app with embedded audio and images

Tags: web-apps, audio, ipad-app, offline, survey

I'm looking for a tool which will let us collect data on iPads out in the field, far from 3G.

#### Requirements

- question type of multiple select amongst different (embedded images) (ie, touch the image corresponding to the question)
- embedded audio clips (ie, play the sound, then touch the associated image)
- somehow easily extract CSV data later on (presumably after syncing with online database)
- ability to replace English questions with custom (unicode) text would be a bonus
- doesn't have to be free, but in the low hundreds of dollars for a few dozen survey responses, on a couple of devices.

#### What I've investigated so far:

- QuickTap Surveys: embedded video (and presumably audio) requires connectivity
- SurveyPocket: embedded video *should* work (in the "media bunker") but it doesn't actually show up, in my tests
- SurveyGizmo: embedded audio requires connectivity
  QuestionPro: the website says it should work, but the rep I spoke to say it's not possible.

I can sort of see a solution where a laptop hosts the data files (and runs a web server), which the iPad points to, but that's going to be messy. Or even running LimeSurvey on a laptop, and pointing the iPad to the whole survey

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Surveypal](http://surveypal.com). Surveypal has mobile app called [Surveypal Go](https://itunes.apple.com/TR/app/id884056605) which is currently running version 0.1, but will be upgraded to 1.0 in next few weeks.  The 1.0 version will be available for Android and iPhone via Play Store and App Store, respectively.

Here's the detailed answers on your requirements:

> question type of multiple select amongst different (embedded images) (ie, touch the image corresponding to the question)

If the element you are referring is the image selection element, then **yes** Surveypal has it available and it is optimized for touch devices such as iPad. There is also wide range of different kind of elements, all heavily customizable. Also the survey styles can be extensively set with the style editor.

> embedded audio clips (ie, play the sound, then touch the associated image)

There is video element coming out in two weeks and it shall be soon after that be officially supported by the Surveypal Go too. There isn't quite yet actual audio element but it will be available in the near future, too. But since the Surveypal Go 1.0's implementation logic is that it crawls through the original answer form HTML, the video and audio files can be downloaded and used offline by adding them as code snippets through the tool. A little hacky but works.

> somehow easily extract CSV data later on (presumably after syncing with online database)

Surveypal supports exporting of result data to Excel, PowerPoint, Word and PDF via their tool. You can also explore the data in the actual tool, where it can be seen as graphs and filtered extensively.

> ability to replace English questions with custom (unicode) text would be a bonus

You can customize all the texts (UTF-8) on answer forms.

> doesn't have to be free, but in the low hundreds of dollars for a few dozen survey responses, on a couple of devices.

It's not free with the cheapest plan being the *Pro* with price of 17 dollars per month (if I'm not mistaken). There is also possibility to try it 30 days for free.

Comment: Oh, hooray for an answer :) Are you saying that Surveypal downloads the videos for you, or you need to do it yourself and convert them somehow?

Comment: @SteveBennett: What I am saying, is that if you have HTML5 video element such as `<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="<some-server>/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>` on your survey, it shall work even though it is still not officially supported. The implementation is done so, that it goes through the HTML and downloads pretty much all URLs to local file system and then uses those. This will be available as more encouraged version later.

Comment: And in case you happen to choose to try out the Surveypal Go and you have anything to ask, don't hesitate to contact me for support. My email is available on my profile.