# Looking for Google-Integrated Offline Surveys

Tags: offline, gps, google-drive, survey

My situation is I'm looking for something that can create a survey that can fill three requirements. Does anyone know of a tool than can do this?

1. Work offline and upload later
2. Automatically grab the geolocation from the mobile device used
3. Integrate with Google Sheets to streamline the uploading of information.

A little background, I'm investigating doing surveys of camps where there may or may not be data coverage. The current solution involves writing down things by hand or shuffling around files, I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Something that is free or discounted for nonprofits would also be nice, but is less important than doing the job.

Comment: Just use any tool that works on your target platform, can save to csv and save your results to your Google Drive folder for automatic syncing when you get back online.

Comment: Although the following answer doesn't integrate into Google Sheets, it does support offline mode and is the best I've found so far: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/offline-survey-app-with-embedded-audio-and-images/16990#16990